# Prevent automatically appending file extension when renaming file

Tags: finder, file-extensions

I originally have a file called `config.yml`. When I go into Finder and change its name to `config.yml.old`, it appears to have changed the extension. However, opening the file in TextWrangler reveals that Mac has just appended a "hidden" `.yml` at the end, causing the filename to be `config.yml.old.yml`.

Right now, the only way I can append an extension is by going to Terminal and running `mv path/to/config.yml path/to/config.yml.old`. Is there actually a way to use the GUI to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to Finder
2. open Finder Preferences
3. Uncheck "Show warning before changing an extension"

Optionally, check "Show all filename extensions" to verify that Mac did not automatically append extensions when you add your own.