# Finder rejecting/renaming file extension?

Tags: finder, file-extensions

I was just attempting to set up a local web project, and came across a peculiar behavior. If I try to change an existing filetype from anything to `.scss`, Finder ends up rejecting the new filetype and appending the old one to it.

Renaming `styles.css > styles.scss` becomes `styles.scss.css`

Renaming `blank.txt > blank.scss` becomes `blank.scss.txt`

If I use terminal or a text editor to rename and save the file as `styles.scss`, finder just leaves off the extension and shows it as `styles`.

This doesn't happen with a `.sass` extension, so I can just use that for now - but I have other projects that use `.scss` so I'd like to be able to get around this if possible. Has anyone run into this issue, or found a way to resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer in a related question here: [Prevent automatically appending file extension when renaming file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142886/prevent-automatically-appending-file-extension-when-renaming-file)

The solution was to turn on the `Show all filename extensions` option in the Finder preferences; for some reason having it disabled forces Finder to append a "sensible" extension to files. This also solved a problem where my `.gitignore` and `.htaccess` files were being appended with an invisible `.txt`